# GCM service not avalible

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I follow the example of http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/ , every thing is fine but its alway response SERVICE_NOT_AVALIBLE
The device time is correctly setup, package name is correct,too.
could anyone help me in this case

my MainActivity.java

```
Button btnRegId;
EditText etRegId;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
String regid;
String PROJECT_NUMBER = "943411953393";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetRegId);
    etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegId);

    btnRegId.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void getRegId(){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                }
                regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                Log.i("GCM",  msg);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getRegId();
}

My AndroidManifest.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gmc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.gmc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gmc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gmc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmMessageHandler" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: In which device you are testing this? SERVICE_NOT_AVALIBLE generally occured when google play store is not up to date in device. Try to update your google play store on your device.

Comment: i tested in ASUS ZENPHONE 5 and google play store is up to date. help me plz

Comment: Does the error occur at `gcm.register()`?

Comment: yes, it does !!! could u plz tell me why ?

Comment: Have you enabled the GCM API in the Developers Console?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
     String msg = "";
     int backoff = 2000;
     try {
          if (gcm == null) {
               gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
          }
     }
     catch (IOException ex) { 
          ex.printStackTrace()
     }
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
          try {
               regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
               msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
               Log.i("GCM",  msg);
               break;
          } 
          catch (IOException ex) {
               msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
               backoff =backoff * 2;
               Thread.sleep(backoff);
          }
     }
     return msg;
}
```

you need to try several attempts increasing the wait time for each try.

Comment: its still not working and logcat show that
02-04 12:33:36.196: W/ActivityManager(92): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) }: not found

Comment: are you getting RegistrationID?
remove <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER" /> from your manifest

Comment: from the error in logcat it seems your GCM message does not have the extras that you are extracting from the intent..
Have you added the extras key in your Message while sending it from server.

Comment: what is extras key? is that PROJECT_NUMBER ? i want to register id of device to GCM so i just declare PROJECT_NUMBER which i get from sole.developers.google.com

Comment: for a complete tutorial read this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql

Comment: i do this example too, but it still not woring :'(